# ''Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position'' using openlayers js

Tags: openlayers, geojson, geoserver

it's been some days i tried to solve this problem but i cant get the right answer; I am trying to insert a map with wfs request from geoserver with openlayers tool but i get this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Jl (ol.js:342)
    at wm.k.Pa (ol.js:342)
    at T.<anonymous> (ol.js:340)
```

and this is my code :

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<center>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
</center> 
<script>
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/opengeo/ows?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=opengeo:comgeo&' +
          'maxFeatures=50'+
          'outputFormat=application%2Fjson' ;

        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });



      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      })
        ],
        target: document.getElementById('mapid'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-9, 30],
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 5
        })
      });

</script> 

</HTML>
```

I don't know where is the problem because i didn't found anythig with json problems and openlayers... Thank you

Comment: Hey, could you also upload the response that your application is getting when it hits this url? http://localhost:8080/geoserver/opengeo/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=opengeo:comgeo&axFeatures=50outputFormat=application/json

Comment: @OliverBarnwell it gives me the geojson farmat of my map file.

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection".....

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error or see whatever you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Your WFS request is invalid. Change

```
'maxFeatures=50'
```

to

```
'maxFeatures=50&'
```

You are also not setting the BBOX of the WFS request. So you should either remove the bbox strategy, or add

```
&BBOX=' + extent.toString()
```

to your WFS url.

Comment: I did change all that but i got the same Error.

Comment: Look at the response from GeoServer in you developer console and check the error message in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue, so my answer may also help others.

It turned out for me that *some* layers I was requesting (but not all) where indeed returning XML rather than JSON. This was tricky to debug as I was requesting multiple layers in a loop and some would return JSON as expected and some would not, leading you to think that they *all* are fine as you would see some of the layers displayed on the map.

In my case this was due to the server running out of memory retrieving the query results for those specific layers, and so an XML error page was returned as per below:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOExceptionorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results. Ran out of memory retrieving query results. Java heap space
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I'd suggest loading the URL of *all* layers directly in a web browser or using browser developer tools to examine the server response for each, even if you are fairly sure they should be returning JSON.